# Convert double to binary representation

Tags: dart, types, bit-manipulation

I'm using bit shift operators on `int`s to convert to binary representation like that:

```
String toBinary(int i) {
  var bytes = Uint8List(8);
  bytes[0] = i >> 56;
  bytes[1] = i >> 48;
  bytes[2] = i >> 40;
  bytes[3] = i >> 32;
  bytes[4] = i >> 24;
  bytes[5] = i >> 16;
  bytes[6] = i >> 8;
  bytes[7] = i;
  return String.fromCharCodes(bytes);
}
```

Now I need to do the same thing for `double`s, but `double` does not define bit shift operators. However, as `double`s are also represented in 64 bit, is there a way to convert them to binary format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Dart already provides a [ByteData](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html) class so in this case you can avoid using the bit shift operation and do instead:

```dart
  var byteData = ByteData(8);
  byteData.setUint64(0, 256);
  var bytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
```

which will produce the same byte list.
Given that you can use the `setFloat64` method on `ByteData` to set a double and then get the binary representation.

Comment: Be careful to notice which byte order the `setInt64`/`setFloat64` operations use. The default is big endian. You should decide whether you want that or little endian.